# Trying to run template multiple times depending on dynamic variable array in the pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am trying to find the git difference from the previous commit in one of folders in my repo and trying to loop different folder names. At the end I need to call template . To simplify the question, I have not mentioned that here. When I try to split the array at the `each` statement , it is NOT working as expected . can some one help me over this

Below is the pipeline .

```
jobs:
      - job: 'First_Job_Name'
        continueOnError: false
        steps:
        - checkout: self
          fetchDepth: 0
        - task: PowerShell@2
          name : myvar
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              $gitDiff=git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only HEAD | Select-String -Pattern "pro"
              $specificContent = $gitDiff -split '\r?\n'
              $secondElements  = @()
              foreach ($filePath in $specificContent) {
                  $splitPath = $filePath -split '/'
                  if ($splitPath.Length -gt 1) {
                  $secondElement = $splitPath[1]
                  $secondElements += $secondElement
                  Write-Host "Second Element: $secondElement"
                  }
              }
              Write-Host "Second Elements: $($secondElements -join ',')"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_VAR;isOutput=true]$($secondElements -join ',')"
      - job: 'Second_Job_Name'
        dependsOn: 'First_Job_Name'
        variables:
          # Define MY_VAR to be get its value from the first job's variable
          MY_VAR: $[ dependencies.First_Job_Name.outputs['myvar.MY_VAR'] ]
        continueOnError: false
        steps:
        - task: Bash@3
          displayName: Using var passed from first job
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
                echo $(MY_VAR)
            failOnStderr: false

        - ${{ each env in split('$(MY_VAR)', ',')}}:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: 'Test'
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                Write-Host '============================================================================================'
                Write-Host  'element: '${{env}}
                Write-Host '============================================================================================'
```